# Do I get early access bonus items everytime I create a new character?

Tags: portal-knights

On Portal Knights, you get a nice Cape and Flag for buying the game while it is on Early Access.

Are these bonuses only once or do I get them every time I create a new character?

Answer (score 1):

You can get these with each new character. In the in-game menu select DLC Shop and redeem the DLC. This will add a gift box to your backpack. Place and break the gift box to access the items.

You can even do this multiple times with each character.